# paroller.js not working good on first load of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I hard refresh the page in middle section, then `paroller js` `transform: translateY();` css not working properly on div `<div class="col col-6" data-paroller-factor="0.4" data-paroller-type="foreground" data-paroller-direction="vertical">`, after that when i scroll this its working fine..  I want that this should be work fine on first hard refresh... when We wo simple refresh of page this also woke fine, but when we see middle of page then do hard refresh `Ctrl+F5`  `transform: translateY();` css not working properly.

Source url: https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js/

Source demo url:  https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=145.0_2

After hard refresh this incorrect css added: (On middle of the page, without scroll)

`transform: translateY(318px);`

After scroll: (Correct css apply):
`transform: translateY(-16px);`

Here is my below code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:400px;"></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-6" data-paroller-factor="0.4" data-paroller-type="foreground" data-paroller-direction="vertical">
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/3" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card vertical</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                  <code>data-paroller-factor="0.4" data-paroller-type="foreground"
                      data-paroller-direction="vertical"</code>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-6">
      <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/3" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Card vertical</h4>
              <p class="card-text">
                  <code></code>
              </p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div style="height:400px;"></div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/js/paroller/jquery.paroller.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('[data-paroller-factor]').paroller();
    $(function () {
       $(window).paroller();
    });


$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.paroller').paroller({
  factor: 0.4,
  type: 'foreground'
});
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution which is best:
Use latest file of js for `"jquery.paroller.min.js"`

`Download js` and `Replace` this:

`https://github.com/tgomilar/paroller.js/releases/tag/v1.4.6`